# Indy IdFtp - network connection was aborted by local system

Tags: delphi-7, indy, indy10

I use Indy 10 and the `TIdFTP` component. It's working with the FTP protocol, but I have this error when I want to upload a `.zip` file to a server over FTPS/SSL.

Encryption: Required explicit FTP over TLS

Error is:

> network connection was aborted by local system

This is my code:

```pascal
var
  fileList: TStringList;
  i : integer;
  ToUpload : String;
  fs: TFileStream;
  LHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
begin
  try
    LHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
    with IdFTP1 do
    begin
      if chkSSL.Checked then
      begin
        IOHandler := LHandler;
        LHandler.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvSSLv3,sslvTLSv1,sslvTLSv1_1,sslvTLSv1_2];
        LHandler.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmClient;
        UseTLS := utUseExplicitTLS;
        DataPortProtection := ftpdpsPrivate;
      end;
      if IdFTP1.Connected then
        Disconnect;
      Username := edUserName;
      Password := edPassword;
      Host := edAddress;
      if not Connected then
        Connect;
    end;
    IdFTP1.ChangeDir(edPath + 'LocalXMLs/');
    
    if FileExists(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+'XMLs\LocalXMLs\LocalXMLs.zip') then
    begin
      ToUpload := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+'XMLs\LocalXMLs\LocalXMLs.zip';
      try
        try
          CurrStep := 3;
          Application.ProcessMessages;
          prgTotal.Max := 1;
          ToUpload := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+'XMLs\LocalXMLs\LocalXMLs.zip';
          try
            try
              fs := TFileStream.Create(ToUpload, fmOpenRead);
              IdFTP1.TransferType := ftBinary;
              IdFTP1.Put(fs, ExtractFileName(ToUpload));
              Memo1.Lines.Add('3.Upload LocalXMLs.zip OK');
            except
              on E: Exception do
              begin
                Memo1.Lines.Add('Error: '+ e.Message);
                FPut := true;
              end;
            end;
          finally
            fs.Free;
          end;
        except
          on E: Exception do
          begin
            Memo1.Lines.Add('Error: '+ e.Message);
            FPut := true;
          end;
        end;
      finally
        //fs.Free;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    IdFTP1.Quit;
    Screen.Cursor := crDefault;
    prgTotal.Position := 0;
    LHandler.Free;
    FPut := true;
  end;
end;
```

I call this method:

```pascal
FPut := false;
UploadXmlFilesWithIDFTP;
while not FPut do
  Application.ProcessMessages;
...
procedure TFm_SyncMain.IdFTP1WorkEnd(Sender: TObject;
  AWorkMode: TWorkMode);
begin
  FGet := True;
  FPut := True;
  edSizeInfo.Text := 'completed.';
  prgTotal.Position := 0;
end;
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Did you try you code against another FTP server?

Comment: No. I have already tried against a server. Works on some computers but not on others

Comment: I'm confused by your answer. You have tried the same code (FTP client, the one you show) on different computers and some are working and other are not. Are all those tests targeting the same FTP server? There maybe many source of this error and I'm try to narrow the source (Could be error in you code, could be firewall, could be server, could be OpenSSL, and probably others as well). By the way, on which line EXACTLY does the error occurs? Have tried running your project under the debugger?

Comment: Is `TIdFTP.Passive` set to True or False? It is False by default. Have you tried it with True yet? It makes a big difference if your client is running behind a NAT/proxy. Also, `TIdFTP.Put()` has an overload that takes a local filename, you don't need to use `TFileStream` directly.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  my friend @fpiette, answer of your first question is true, the target server is same!. I checked OpenSSL version, firewall, NAT/proxy and etc.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you for your answer,  TIdFTP.Passive was true. I cleared my code and deleted TFileStream. I'm going to debug this code, before of this I could not debug because of my IP, hosting opened my ip now. I'll back after debug. Thanks. sorry for my poor english.

Comment: The error occurs on this line:    IdFTP1.Put(ToUpload, ExtractFileName(ToUpload));

Comment: @fpiette I use ICS components too. could you give me a sample code to use TSslFtpClient over TLS?

Comment: @Mehdijafari the only other suggestions I can make are to get rid of the `LHandler.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmClient` assignment, and get rid of `sslvSSLv3`. The rest of the code looks fine to me.

Comment: @RemyLebeau . I'll delete sslvSSLv3 and Which mode should I set?

Comment: @Mehdijafari don't set any `Mode` at all, the default should suffice. A passive transfer uses an inbound server socket, so you would need to use `sslmServer` for that, but `sslmClient` would be needed for the control connection. The default `Mode` should allow `TIdFTP` to use both modes. Otherwise, you would have to manually set `sslmClient` on the control connection's IOHandler, and set `sslmServer` on the data connection's IOHandler in the `OnDataChannelCreate` event.

Comment: Thank you @RemyLebeau. I will inform you after the test.

Comment: @Mehdijafari questions about ICS are to be posted in the dedicated forum at https://en.delphipraxis.net/forum/37-ics-internet-component-suite/

Comment: @RemyLebeau I tested this code but this error still occurs .

Comment: @Mehdijafari when the error happens, what does the call stack look like?